# UIButton failing to resize text correctly for iPhone 4/5 screen sizes. (using intrinsicContentSize)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIView` setup in a xib with four buttons in it. The text is left aligned with left edge content inset set to 20 on all of them. The constraints can be seen below:

[image]

The xib's width is set to 320 for the width of the iPhone 4 and 5. When this view is added to a view controller I make the frame's width the same as the current screen size e.g. iPhone6 and the buttons will stretch horizontally. Now when I set the title text I want the buttons to grow in height to accommodate the text.

I subclassed UIButton and overrode this method:

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {

        let labelSize = titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max)) ?? CGSizeZero
        let desiredButtonSize = CGSizeMake(labelSize.width + titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right, labelSize.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom)
        return desiredButtonSize
    }
```

I then set the title labels as desired. For the iPhone6 and upwards it works perfectly:

[image]

However for the iPhone 4 or 5 I get this result:

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong on this? Would really appreciate some pointers. Thanks!

Comment: what version of iOS is on the 4/5 vs the 6?

Comment: 9.3 on all simulators I'm testing @jacobbullock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use the button's frame to determine the size the title will fit. You want to use the title's frame. `titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max))` will determine the height of the label as though the labels width were the entirety of the button's frame. But you have an inset that will not allow the title to be laid out that way, so it is under estimating the height. This is way your label overflows the bounds of the button. It should be:

```
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {

        let labelSize = titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake((self.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)!, CGFloat.max)) ?? CGSizeZero
        let desiredButtonSize = CGSizeMake(labelSize.width + titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right, labelSize.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom)
        return desiredButtonSize
    }
```

**Edit**

Depending on your constraints you may also need

```
override func layoutSubviews() { 
    super.layoutSubviews() self.titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width 
}
```

Comment: Gave this a shot. Overflows on the iPhone 4/5 AND the six using this method.

Comment: What is the greater than or equal to constraint?

Comment: I created a sample project and to test my code. I saw the overflow your way and my code caused it to go away on all devices. The only difference I can see is the >= height constraint, and I set the button's content inset not the inset on the titleLabel. So maybe if you post how you do that. I just set the left inset in IB.

Comment: I'll give it a shot later. Out now. I'll let you know the result. Thanks

Comment: What did you do with your height constraint by the way?

Comment: override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width
    }

Comment: now it works! Thank you. if you maybe want to edit your answer to add it in might be good for others to see.